Text and code over margins in R Markdown .pdf knitting
I'm trying to knit a R Markdown document as a .pdf, but when doing so the text and code go over the pages' margings (see image below -- if you can't tell, every long-enough text is truncated on the right).

(Relevant) code looks simply like the following:

---
title: "xxx"
author: "xxx"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

and then some chunks of code (nor relevant for this matter).
How can I fix this so all text and code is within margins?

After several tries, one solution seems to be including the following chunk at the beginning:
```{r, global_options, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message = FALSE, tidy.opts = list(width.cutoff = 30), tidy = TRUE)

